# Negation of Specified Range of Quantifiers

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, quantifiers

I'm new to math and self studying at the moment, and I came upon a situation where mechanically negating has led to something that looked wrong. Here is what i think is correct.

$\neg (\forall x \in R$ s.t. $x < 5, \exists y \in R$ s.t. $y <3, $ s.t. $x < 1)$

$\exists x \in R$ s.t. $x < 5, \forall y \in R$ s.t. $y<3, $ s.t. $ x \geq 1$

At first the instinct is to write the same statement that I wrote with $x \geq 5$ and $y \geq 3$. But it seemed wrong to me since:

For all dogs younger than 2, there's an owner older than 4, and the owner has a pigeon.

The correct negation of the above seems to be:
There exists a dog younger than 2, for all owners older than 4, and the owner doesn't have a pigeon.

Have I totally misunderstood this?

Comment: The formula is correct.

Comment: We do not apply negation to the condition "restricting" the quantifier. Consider a more readable example: "Every Man is a Philosopher" that we can symbolize with $\forall x (Mx \to Px)$ i.e. with $(\forall x : Mx) Px$. The negation will be: "There is a Man that is not a Philosopher" and not "There is a non-Man ..."

Comment: Aha! Thanks so much!